# Create blockchain from scratch with smart contract support

Tags: private-blockchain, evm, nodejs

I'm looking to create a private blockchain from **scratch** for an academic project with its own cryptocurrency (looking to make a fiat-based stablecoin).

I managed to code a simple infrastructure on my local machine (with nodejs server executing all blockchain requests). But now I'm looking to add a smart contract feature to it. But that's where I stumbled. I am trying to add the **vm package** from **ethereumjs** project ( https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-monorepo/tree/master/packages/vm ) with custom genesis block to locally execute the smart contract function (on each node).

However it's the **gas fee** that worries me. Apparently every request, method, deployment requires a gas and that it's hard coded into the vm package. I want to run and execute smart contract on my blockchain **without any fee** whatsoever. Is that even possible? If yes, please do enlighten on the how.

Comment: can't you set the gas price to 0x00 for all transactions? or set the gas price for all opcodes to 0? 
if your smart contracts can be called freely, it can lead to security issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fees are what keeps the network going. Without them, your infrastructure will likely just become centralized. If you are looking into reduced fees, you should make it a layer 2 like Polygon.

Comment: I intend to have fee per transaction (which will be paid with the new cryptocurrency not with ether) but for smart contract execution. Is that possible?

Comment: Yes, this is what Layer 2's do.